# schedule post using facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am able to post on my page like bellow

```
client.Post( "postId"/feeds", messagePost);
```

But now I want to schedule post the same page.

I tried to find on web but dident got any solution.

Comment: What Facebook SDK you are using? Since Facebook doesn't have a .NET  SDK and there are multiple third party SDKs.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk I am using this

Comment: did you tried? full sample ? What is **postId** ?

Comment: Useful for create sample: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Actually PostId is PageID where you want to schedule the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
   client.Post("postId/feeds", new
        {
            access_token = "Your access token",
            scheduled_publish_time = "Time as unix timestamp",
            message = "Your message",
            published = "0"
        });
```

I have never used the Facebook SDK before, but these links where very helpful:

[Facebook Error 100: You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002547/facebook-error-100-you-cannot-specify-a-scheduled-publish-time-on-a-published-p)

[Posts scheduled via Graph API frequently do not get published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044251/posts-scheduled-via-graph-api-frequently-do-not-get-published)

Comment: I'm on my mobile right now but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp should get you in the right direction.

Comment: `Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;`

Comment: Yes that would work. That will give you the timestamp of the current time.

Comment: Maybe possible post in https://www.facebook.com/cocacola?fref=ts with schedule. What is ***postId*** ?