# Facebook Graph API Scheduled Posts created but not published

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, django-facebook

I'm using [django-facebook's Open Facebook API](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/open_facebook/api.html) to try to defer a post with an image to a facebook page. The (relevant part of the) code is:

```
graph_api = OpenFacebook(integration.long_lived_page_token)
message = "something"
picture = "http://example.com/image.jpg"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('07-25-2014 06:40 pm UTC', '%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p %Z')
timestamp = timestamp = int(time.mktime(d.timetuple()))
try:
    facebook_response = graph_api.set('/{0}/feed'.format(
    facebook_page_id), message=message,
    link=picture, picture=picture,
    scheduled_publish_time=timestamp, published=0)
except:
...
```

This seems to work fine (I get the post id on facebook_response) but when the time comes to post this scheduled post nothing happens. When I check at the facebook page I see an error saying  'Sorry, something went wrong publishing this scheduled post' and offers to delete it or post it then. So, I can't seem to figure out what am I doing wrong.
I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044251/posts-scheduled-via-graph-api-frequently-do-not-get-published) but it does not offer a good answer.

Oh, I forgot to say when I remove timestamp and published=0 parameters (i.e. I post on that exact moment), the post gets created and published on the page's feed.

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve it ?Did you app in dev mode to ?

Comment: I just used a celery job to look for scheduled posts every minute and post them.

Comment: Hi Thanks for information. I make it work i'n not sure why. Maybe because and publish the application without any extra permissions.